# @synchronized blocks and selectors inBackground and afterDelay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asynchronous, thread-safety

Currently I am having trouble with what appears to be a locking problem preventing my code from continuing to run. I suspect the problem is based in the way that the @synchronized blocks function with performSelector:AfterDelay:. Does the lock persist through the delay, or is the selector scheduled outside the lock?

Here's the code if you want to take a look. Essentially, locateEvents is called a large number of times, but only really needs to run once every so often as new event location data comes in (ie, if it keeps being called).

```
-(void) locateEvents
{
   @synchronized(self)
   {
     if(!locating)
     {
        locating = true;
        shouldLocate = false;

        for(Event* e in provider.allEvents)
        {
            if(e.coordinate.latitude)
                [self queueEventForMap:e];
        }

        [self performSelector:@selector(stopLocating) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];

      }else{
        shouldLocate = true;
      }
   }

}

-(void) stopLocating
{
  locating = false;

  if(shouldLocate)
     [self locateEvents];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional testing, it appears that the lock does not follow the scheduled selector. The problem that I was having above was caused by the thread dying and leaving the scheduled selector un-launched.